# my url parameter is not reaching my view in django

Tags: django, django-views

The url parameter is not reaching my view.

My urls is defined as follow where the category_code is the parameter:

```
# posting image for a post
url(r'^post/photo/(?P<category_code>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_photo, name='post_photo_url'),
```

and my view as follow where I expect my url parameter category_code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_photo(request, category_code):
    """
    Post all the PHOTO URL for that POST
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PhotoURLSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            photoUrl = serializer.save()
            set_thumbnail(photoUrl.post_id, category_code, photoUrl.url)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

The set_thumbnail function is as follow:

```
def set_thumbnail(post_id, category_code, thumbnail_url):
    if category_code == 0: # mobile category
        pass

    elif category_code == 1: # Electronic category
        pass
    elif category_code == 2: # Car category
        autoPost = AutoPost.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        autoPost.set_thumbnail_url(thumbnail_url)

    elif category_code == 3: # Furniture category
        pass

    elif category_code == 4: # Fashion category
        pass
    elif category_code == 5: # Real Estate category
        housePost = RealEstate.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        housePost.set_thumbnail_url(thumbnail_url)
        housePost.save()
        pass
    elif category_code == 6: # Jobs and services category
        pass
    elif category_code == 7: # Show Category
        pass
```

But when the view is executing,
the function set_thumbnail is getting null from category code, even though from the server log I can see that the parameter has been passed, it's the first line and the parameter value is 2

[image]

The URL is receiving data from an android clients using rest api.

```
/* PHOTO FOR POSTS */
    @POST("/post/photo/{category_code}/")
    Call<PhotoURL> createPhotoURL(@Body PhotoURL photoURL, @Path("category_code") int categoryCode);
```

Comment: What is `set_thumbnail`? Show the code.

Comment: I just edited the post and incorporated the `set_thumbnail` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category_code` is a string so won't be equal to any of the ints in the `set_thumbnail` method. Either convert it to an int or use strings for comparison.

Comment: it works now, but I dont understand how the parameter `category_code` reaches the server as a string despite being declared as an integer from the android client.

Comment: How would Django know what your Android client does? It just gets the URL - /post/category/2/ - and uses a regex to parse out the "2". But it's still a string.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's even more robust now as I cast it manually to int. thanks.